# Display issues on Ubuntu

Tags: nvidia, display, hardware, fonts

I recently bought brand new Dell Inspiron 15 3000 with windows install. As our company works with ubuntu I format it and install Ubuntu.

After the installation completed the and the ubuntu loaded the font have some strange behavior & display.

Graphic card: NVIDIA GEFORCE.

I took a photo of the screen and attached it bellow (sorry about it) as a link because the ask ubuntu's server had an error.

I don't know if it driver/hardware/software related.

What you recommend me to do??

[ATTACHMENT: Screen photo here - uploaded to the first server i found :)](http://postimg.org/image/ie0roo0yz/full/)

Answer (score 1):

Ensure the Nvidia card which you are running is not restricted ( which includes the Nvidia driver as well) and if the display resolution is still wrong ??

Then proceed as follows:

1. First make sure that you have installed the application gksu:

   Launch a terminal window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type (or copy/paste):

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gksu
   ```

   Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and submit your password. Please note that the password will remain invisible, not even asterisks will show, which is normal.
2. Then type in the same terminal:

   ```
   gksudo nvidia-settings
   ```

   And press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

   Now you can configure your display with this nifty tool from Nvidia itself. Proceed as follows:

   Click "X Server Display Configuration" (top left, second entry).

   On the right in the window: click the tab "Display" (which should be opened already).

   Resolution: click the button that says "Auto", and choose the display resolution that you want.

   Click "Save to X Configuration File".

   Click Close.
3. Reboot your computer. Now the display resolution should be right.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
I'm not sure it resolution related. There some charters missings and some wired graphic beghavior. Currently I'm trying to reinstall the OS & will try your solution as soon as it ready.

Comment: @vembutech: For a 1244 rep user your formatting looks horrible.  Could you please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/595224/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your answers in the future... ;-)